# Catch and Log specific and generic errors MULE 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I 'am building my error handeling section, but I am not getting the right response in the logs. I want to catch the most common errors like, 400, 401, 403, 404 and 500 and the ones that I don't know to get. I would like to log everything properly so that it becomes clear which error it throwing and the associated code.

This is what I implemented so for;

```
<choice-exception-strategy name="Choice_Exception_Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="400" when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == '400']">
            <set-variable variableName="error"
                value="#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]" doc:name="Set error flowVar" />
            <set-variable variableName="ErrorDesc"
                value="#[org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(exception)]"
                doc:name="Set response error message" />
            <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="400"
                doc:name="Set status 400" />
            <logger message="#[&quot;Error: &quot; + flowVars.error + &quot; Response error: &quot; + flowVars.ErrorDesc]"
                level="INFO" doc:name="Log Error" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy
            when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == '401']" doc:name="401">
            <set-variable variableName="error"
                value="#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]" doc:name="Set error flowVar" />
            <set-variable variableName="ErrorDesc"
                value="#[org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(exception)]"
                doc:name="Set response error message" />
            <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="401"
                doc:name="Set status 401" />
            <logger message="#[&quot;Error: &quot; + flowVars.error + &quot; Response error: &quot; + flowVars.ErrorDesc]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log Error"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="404" when="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == '404']">
            <set-variable variableName="error"
                value="#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]" doc:name="Set error flowVar" />
            <set-variable variableName="ErrorDesc"
                value="#[org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(exception)]"
                doc:name="Set response error message" />
            <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="404"
                doc:name="Set status 404" />
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Error"
                message="#[&quot;Error: &quot; + flowVars.error + &quot; Response error: &quot; + flowVars.ErrorDesc]" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="500 or " >
            <set-variable variableName="error"
                value="#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]" doc:name="Set error flowVar" />
            <set-variable variableName="ErrorDesc"
                value="#[org.mule.util.ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(exception)]"
                doc:name="Set response error message" />
            <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="500, 503"
                doc:name="Set status 500" />
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Error"
                message="#[&quot;Error: &quot; + flowVars.error + &quot; Response error: &quot; + flowVars.ErrorDesc]" />
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

And this is output that I get with code above:

```
Message               : Response code 401 mapped as failure.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@5b21fa2f
Element               : /bos-topdesk-sas-km-dl-ms-main/processors/4/ref-sys-api-router/subprocessors/0 @ ref-sys-api.xml:43 (HTTP Request Incidents)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration_Incidents" path="" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP Request Incidents"></http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 401 mapped as failure.
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:429)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:412)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:226)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:131)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:221)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:214)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:213)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

********************************************************************************
 Response error: ResponseValidatorException: Response code 401 mapped as failure.
```

My expected output is that it shows in the logs as below;

```
 {
        "code": 403,
        "Error type: "Access forbidden"
        "message": "You are not allowed to administrate categories."
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is the problem or question? What are the issues your attempt has?

Comment: @aled I am not able to see proper descprition like json+problem structure. I have added the error section above

Comment: What is the actual message that you see in the log with your solution? Actual vs expected results are something that you should consider in almost all questions.

Comment: @aled You are right! I have added that Actual and the expected now